# Copy a binding from one textbox to another

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Hopefully a simple starter question from a newbie...

I have a TextBox whose Text property is bound to a ViewModel and DependencyProperty.

When I click on the TextBox I want a second TextBox (an 'Editor' TextBox) to be assigned the same binding as the first. The outcome being that editing the second 'Editor' TextBox will update the first.

Ultimately I want to be able to click any TextBox and edit it in the same 'Editor' TextBox.

---

My Solution using Option 2... Thanks!!:

```
    private void m_sourceTextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox sourceTextBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (null != sourceTextBox)
        {
            BindingExpression sourceBindExpression = sourceTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

            if (sourceBindExpression != null && sourceBindExpression.ParentBinding != null && sourceBindExpression.ParentBinding.Path != null)
                m_editorTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, sourceBindExpression.ParentBinding);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this

The first, is to have a `SelectedText` property in your ViewModel that your `EditorTextBox` is bound to, and set this value when you click on any of the other `TextBoxes`. For this to work, you'll probably need something like an [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) so you can attach a Command from the ViewModel to the `Click` or `Focus` event of the TextBox.

The other way I can think of doing it is just to do it in code-behind. In the `Click` or `Focus` event of each TextBox, get the `BindingExpression` for the selected TextBox's `TextProperty`, and copy the binding to the `EditorTextBox.Text`.